# Abstract Syntax Tree representing a program in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, tree, while-loop, abstract

I've been given the following Data types:

```
data Aexp = N Integer | V Var | Add Aexp Aexp | Mult Aexp Aexp | Sub Aexp Aexp
data Bexp = Bcon Bool | Eq Aexp Aexp | Le Aexp Aexp | Neg Bexp | And Bexp Bexp
data Stm  = Ass Var Aexp | Skip | Comp Stm Stm | If Bexp Stm Stm | While Bexp Stm | Block DecV DecP Stm | Call Pname
```

For Arithmetic expressions, Boolean expressions and Statements respectively.

I have been asked to return a Stm representing the following program:

```
x:=5;
y:=1;
while ¬(x=1) do
    y:=y*x;
    x:=x-1
```

So far I have the following :

```
p :: Stm
p = (Ass x 5) (Ass y 1) (While (Neg (Eq x 1)) Ass x (Sub x 1) Ass y (Mult y x))
```

I did this simply by writing out the program on paper and then drawing a syntax tree from it. Firstly I'm not sure if this is actually correct as I don't really know how to prove it. And secondy when I compile I get lots of errors like:

```
denotational.hs:122:10: Not in scope: `x'
denotational.hs:122:20: Not in scope: `y'
denotational.hs:122:41: Not in scope: `x'
denotational.hs:122:51: Not in scope: `x'
denotational.hs:122:58: Not in scope: `x'
denotational.hs:122:67: Not in scope: `y'
denotational.hs:122:75: Not in scope: `y'
denotational.hs:122:77: Not in scope: `x'
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're mixing up Haskell variables and variables in your language. The Haskell variables `x` and `y` aren't defined anywhere, so you can't use them in you definition of `p`. You probably want to do `Ass "x" 5` etc., assuming that `type Var = String`.

Comment: You are correct in saying that `type Var = String` however when I tried that with all the variables I get all kinds of errors. For example `The function Ass is applied to four arguments, but its type Var -> Aexp -> Stm has only two` or `The function While' is applied to 7 arguments, but its type Bexp -> Stm -> Stm has only two` I think I might be constructing the actual statement incorrectly compared to the data type I'm given. But I can't really see how.

Comment: Juxtaposition is pretty much always function application in Haskell. For example, you're applying the result of `(Ass x 5)` to two arguments: `(Ass y 1)` and `(While (Neg (Eq x 1)) Ass x (Sub x 1) Ass y (Mult y x))`. Since you've also already applied `Ass` to `x` and `5`, the compiler complains that you've given it a total of four arguments. There is a similar problem in the call to `While`.

Comment: You mention correctness in your problem. One simple solution once you iron out the syntax errors is to write an interpreter that takes your syntax tree and evaluates it to a result!

Comment: @DavidYoung That makes sense thanks, I'm just not really sure how to get around this problem? For example how to I assign (Ass x 5) and then re-use it later whithout causing this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AST is a representation of the syntax of the (sub-)language. Everything that is in that sublanguage must be in your AST and nothing of Haskell.

So, assuming your language is fully represented by a list of `Stm`s you might write

```
x:=5;
```

as

```
fragx :: [Stm]
fragx = [ Ass "x" (N 5) ]
```

which captures in the tree structure of your AST all of the information in that fragment from the sort of literal to the name of the variable being bound. A larger example

```
x:=5;
y:=1;
```

is

```
frag2 :: [Stm]
frag2 = [ Ass "x" (N 5)
        , Ass "y" (N 1)
        ]

fragy :: [Stm]
fragy = [ Ass "y" (N 1) ]
```

with

```
frag2 == fragx ++ fragy
```

which demonstrates how we can talk about appending two programs syntactically as the Haskell function `(++) :: [Stm] -> [Stm] -> [Stm]`. Again, these fragments are simple static representations of the syntax of the sublanguage. There is nothing tricky going on in the Haskell side, in particular, no bleeding of Haskell variables into sublanguage variables.

The adding final fragment might look like

```
fragAll :: [Stm]
fragAll = fragx ++ fragy
          ++ [ While (Neg (Eq (V "x") (N 1))) (Block ...)
             ]
```

but it cannot be completed without looking into the structure of the arguments to `Block`.